# Renormalization scale dependence of S, T parameter of Electroweak precision test

Tags: standard-model, electroweak

In Peskin, Takeuchi(1992) paper([link](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.46.381)), oblique parameters S and T, U are defined as

(Eqn 3.12)
$\alpha S\equiv 4e^2[\Pi'_{33}(0)-\Pi'_{3Q}(0)], \\ \alpha T\equiv \frac{e^2}{s^2c^2m_Z^2}[\Pi_{11}(0)-\Pi_{33}(0)], \\ \alpha U\equiv 4e^2[\Pi'_{11}(0)-\Pi'_{33}(0)]$

where, 
$\quad ig^{\mu\nu}\Pi_{XY}+(q^\mu q^\nu\text{terms}) \equiv \int d^4x \hspace{1mm}e^{-iqx}\langle J^\mu_X(x)J^\nu_Y(0))$.

Their dominant 1-loop correction is calculated as

$S=\frac{1}{12\pi}\ln\left[\frac{m_H^2}{m_{H,ref}^2}\right] -\frac{1}{6\pi}\ln\left[\frac{m_t^2}{m_{t,ref}^2}\right],\\
 T=-\frac{3}{16\pi}\ln\left[\frac{m_H^2}{m_{H,ref}^2}\right] +\frac{1}{16\pi s^2c^2}\left[\frac{m_t^2-m_{t,ref}^2}{m_Z^2}\right],\\
 U=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left[\frac{m_t^2}{m_{t,ref}^2}\right].$

where $m_{H,ref}(m_{t,ref})$ are reference value of Higgs-boson(top quark) mass from which S, T, and U are defined.

In my own 1-loop calculation of top and higgs particles using dimensional regularization, these reference masses are renormalization scale($\mu$), which is coming from cheating dimension of electric charge as $e\rightarrow e\mu^{4-d}$. So S and T, U parameters become renormalization scale dependent.

I guess original calculation was done with cut-off regularization, so that their reference masses are cut-off of each loop, which is often replaced with mass of heavy particle in that loop.

In any cases, S, T, U parameters seem to depend on arbitrary scale($\mu$ and cutoff). If gauge boson self energy($\Pi_{XY}$) are renormalized quantity, by their definition, oblique parameters can depend on renormalization scale and we can set the renormalization scale such that S,T, and U=0 at those scales. But if they are from bare field(not renormalizaed Green function), then I think S, T and U parameter should not depend on renormalization scale.

In the appendix of this paper, electroweak observables are expressed in terms of $\alpha S,\alpha T,\alpha U $.

For example, $\quad g_R^2=(1+\alpha T)^2\frac{5}{9}(s_0^2+\frac{\alpha}{c^2-s^2}(\frac{1}{4}S-s^2c^2T))^2$.

So I guess that renormalization scale dependence in coupling($e^2$) should be compensated for by scale dependence in $\Pi^{(')}_{XY}-\Pi^{(')}_{X'Y'}$  so that $\alpha S(T,U)$ should remain independent on renormalization scale.

However, in this paper, scale dependence of coupling and self-energy don't seem to cancle since the latter has two different scales - $m_{H,ref}^2, m_{t,ref}^2$. Also strangely, $\alpha$ is evaluated at $m_Z^2$ in this paper.

In this case, where $\alpha S, \alpha T, \alpha U$ are $m_{ref}$ dependent, observables that is expressed in terms of $\alpha S, \alpha T, \alpha U$ are also $m_{ref}$ dependent. But this should not be the case.

So my question is how observables can be independent of $m_{ref}$.

Comment: Let me quickly check: You're worried about something other than the usual dependence of S and T on the "reference" Higgs boson mass?  Before the Higgs mass was measured to be ~125GeV, the {S, T} ellipses were generally computed for three different choices of this unknown reference scale (for example, ~120GeV, ~300GeV and ~1000GeV).

Comment: Before higgs discovery, various higgs masses were tried as a reference mass. But in my trials, different reference masses vary the range of top and higgs mass through S, T parameter(within SM). For the scale dependence of observables, after post, I found that $log(\mu^2)$ from loop of fermions is canceled in physical observables whenever $1/\epsilon$ in dimensional regularization is canceled. But not yet checked for Higgs loop(which is more complicated as it involves various particles).